# Error while creating channel in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to create a channel in the deployed hyperledger fabric.
using command

```
peer channel create -o orderer0.orgorderer1:7050 -c mychannel -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx
```

but i am getting error

```
2018-01-18 09:59:05.382 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 011 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken read tcp 10.244.1.8:47112->10.96.99.75:7050: read: connection reset by peer.
2018-01-18 09:59:05.383 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 012 transport: http2Client.notifyError got notified that the client transport was broken unexpected EOF.
Error: rpc error: code = Internal desc = transport is closing
2018-01-18 09:59:05.383 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 013 grpc: addrConn.resetTransport failed to create client transport: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: operation was canceled"; Reconnecting to {orderer0.orgorderer1:7050 <nil>}
2018-01-18 09:59:05.383 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 014 grpc: addrConn.transportMonitor exits due to: grpc: the connection is closing
```

More info 
my hyperledger fabric is deployed on kubernetes. using [link](https://medium.com/@zhanghenry/how-to-deploy-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes-2-751abf44c807)

And is was working fine
now i have used custom cryptographic material for the MSP
and redeployed.
And getting the above error

all the pods in the kubernestes are up and running.

[image]

Comment: When i do wget orderer0.orgorderer1:7050
i am able to get connected. So i dont feel it is a connection issue

Comment: What do you mean by "custom cryptographic material"? Generated not using `cryptogen`?

Comment: yeah, wwe need more clarity on what you mean by "custom cryptographic material". How was this produced?

Comment: Yes i mean not using cryptogen.
 i have used a third party CA to get the certificates. Previously i have did a PoC using the third party CA and it worked. and also did a POC for hyperledger fabric deployement on kubernetes seperately. Now i am combining both and following the same steps

Comment: Is there any solution for this problem? I'm suffering the same issue.

Comment: Nopes.. could'nt figure out the solution for .. also for HLF may be this issue was not priority